# What is the standard for showing tooltip warnings in rustdocs?

Tags: rust, rustdoc

In [`decl_storage!`](https://crates.parity.io/srml_support_procedural/macro.decl_storage.html), it appears that the syntax used for tooltip warnings appears to be `/!\` (i.e. `/!\ Be careful ...`). If it's a tooltip warning it may be preferable to show it in bold or italic text by using HTML syntax (i.e. using HTML such as `<b></b>`). What is the standard for showing tooltip warnings in rustdocs?